# Adding a CSP to a Firefox extension's own HTML page

Tags: firefox-addon, content-security-policy

I have a Firefox extension displaying its own HTML page via a chrome:// url, and scripts in it are running with chrome privileges. For users' security, I want to add a Content Security Policy to this page.

The obvious thing to do is to add it via <meta> tag, but that's not yet supported in Firefox ([bug 663570](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=663570)). **Update:** Bug 663570 was fixed in Firefox 45, but my attempts to use a  tag caused Firefox to crash. [Bug 923902](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=923902) seems to be the new bug to watch.

Is there any way to implement a CSP right now? Some way to fake the appropriate HTTP header for a chrome:// URL?

Comment: There was a user who worked on CSP stuff he was just on irc, ill mention to him you may be in same boat.

Comment: His user name is pastly I cant catch him right now but ill catch him soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question waaay back in the days of XUL add-ons, which are long gone - in this era of WebExtensions, I could [define a CSP in manifest.json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy), although the [default CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy#default_content_security_policy) is plenty secure.